# Define constant in Codeigniter with database values

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hello I am working on multi language website, I have keywords in database. I am creating library to define all that words and load it. but while defining issue with single quote. when I am using defined words in other file getting error Severity:

> Notice Message: Use of undefined constant CONTACT_US - assumed 'CONTACT_US'

here is library code

```
<?php
class Language_lib {
    public function __construct() {
        $CI = & get_instance();
        if ($CI->session->userdata('site_lang') == '') {
            $site_lang = array('site_lang' => 'en');
            $CI->session->set_userdata($site_lang);
        }
        $lang_result = $CI->db->get('prc_site_text');
        $row_lang = $lang_result->result_array();
        if (count($row_lang) > 0) {
            foreach ($row_lang as $row){
                if ($CI->session->userdata('site_lang') == 'fr') {
                    define($row['key_value'], stripslashes($row['french']));
                } else {
                    define($row['key_value'], stripslashes($row['english']));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: and where are you using these constant

Comment: are these constants are global

Comment: yes once I define it I have to use it in all views